# How to point root domain to heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I am using Heroku app and need to point domain to that server. It is working correctly when I am using www subdomain, but when I try to setup it for root domain I cant enter @ in CNAME name because WHM is not allowing. I have used * in CNAME and it redirected all to www subdomain, but I dont need to redirect from root to www, I need root to point to root, and subdomain to that subdomain.

I cant get enter this @ in name field like on picture, I dont use this tool as is on picture, I have WHM.

[image: http://docs.easydns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/aname2.png]

I am folowing this instructions devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain but I am not successful

What should I do.

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal in terms of the RFC 1034 rules for domain names to have a CNAME and any other record present in a particular node. The root node has to have at least an SOA record, and so you cannot use a CNAME in the root node.

The reason for this is as follows ([RFC 1034](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html)) -

> A CNAME RR identifies its owner name as an alias, and
>   specifies the corresponding canonical name in the RDATA section of the
>   RR.  If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
>   present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its aliases
>   cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached CNAME can be
>   used without checking with an authoritative server for other RR types.

Also see this blog - [Why it's a bad idea to put a CNAME record on your root domain](http://joshstrange.com/why-its-a-bad-idea-to-put-a-cname-record-on-your-root-domain/)

Try redirecting the naked domain up to a sub-domain such as www

Comment: I dont need to redirect from root to www, I need root to point to root, and subdomain to that subdomain. I am folowing this instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain but I am not successful.

Comment: I understand that is your desired result, and the RFC standard actually prohibits CNAME records on the apex domain, as I described.

Comment: Some DNS providers allow a CNAME-like configuration - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#cname-functionality-at-the-apex

Comment: I have looked at that, but tool I am using is like this http://cdn.inmotionhosting.com/support/images/stories/reseller/dns-zones.png

Comment: It seems that you cannot achieve the desired result using the DNS tool you have. My suggestion is either to transfer your domain name to another provider which does support it (there are several listed in the heroku article) if this requirement is critical, or use bare domain redirection